# Inserting into MS SQL DB with procedure not working

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I've tried a lot of googling and following some tutorials. I'm using MS SQL and trying to make a simple User table and salt and hashing the password, haven't gotten to the salting part, yet.

The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[User] (
UserID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
Email NVARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
Password BINARY(64) NOT NULL,
FirstName NVARCHAR(45) NULL,
LastName NVARCHAR(45) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_User_UserID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (UserID ASC)
)
```

And the procedure looks like this:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.[uspAddUser]
    @pEmail NVARCHAR(45),
    @pPassword NVARCHAR(45),
    @pFirstName NVARCHAR(45) = NULL,
    @pLastName NVARCHAR(45) = NULL,
    @responseMessage NVARCHAR(250) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO dbo.[User] (Email, Password, FirstName, LastName)
        VALUES (@pEmail, HASHBYTES('SHA_512', @pPassword), @pFirstName, @pLastName)

        SET @responseMessage = 'Success'

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @responseMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH

END
```

When I try to insert with the procedure it won't work:

```
DECLARE @responseMessage NVARCHAR(250)

EXEC dbo.[uspAddUser]
          @pEmail = N'Admin@email.com',
          @pPassword = N'123',
          @pFirstName = N'Admin',
          @pLastName = N'Administrator',
          @responseMessage=@responseMessage OUTPUT

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[User]
```

No results are shown. After inserting normally and then retrieving the results it shows the newly created tuple but with the ID auto incremented like other tuples were created. I'm not really sure where the problem is and would be grateful if someone else understood.

EDIT:

**SOLVED**

Apparently the fault was I used the wrong kind of sha hash. Instead of using SHA_512 I should've used **SHA2_512.**

Comment: Does `@responseMessage` contain an error message?

Comment: Try this out `SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA_512', N'123')` and see if it returns NULL. You can't insert a null password on your table, and your SQL Server version might not support sha 512. Try with `'SHA2_512'`.

Comment: Apparently it was that I didn't use the correct SHA, I should've used 'SHA2_5121 as you mentioned, thanks for the quick answers!

Answer (score 1):

`HASHBYTES('SHA_512', @pPassword)` returns `null` so that insert query gets aborted. Instead, you can use algorithms `SHA2_512` or `SHA2_256` or any other encryption algorithm you want.

Check out [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for more info.

Comment: Yeah that was my bad, thank you for the quick response. It was indeed the fault that I was using SHA_512 instead of SHA2_512.